# Issue with creating stacked column chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a stacked column chart using excel vba.[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt5WK.png)

Following mentioned below is my excel vba code for generating the stacked column chart for the corresponding input data.

```
      Sub to_draw_chart()
         ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked).Select
         ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet2!$A$1:$P$4")
         ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
         ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1000
         ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 250

         ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
         ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select

         ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
         ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
         Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
         ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
         ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
         Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
         ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Select
         Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
         ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(12).Select
         Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
         ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(15).Select
         Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

         ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
         ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
         ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart "
         Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Chart "
      End Sub
```

[outputExpected_VS_output_getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhHSE.jpg)

But when i run this macro, the output i am getting is different. the problem is in the x axis. my x axis should be D0, D1,D2(as you can see in image "Output Expected". But it is different. i have also attached the output i am getting when i run the vba code (Second image).

I am not understanding why my x axis is getting changed which is indeed affecting the code and the output graph.

Manually when i do without using code then i am getting the correct output.

where am i going wrong?

Comment: see my answer below (another option to handle the `Chart` object)

Comment: yes, it worked. thank you very much.

Comment: then please upvote and mark as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Switch Row/Column by adding `ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns`. The following should solve the issue.

```
  Sub to_draw_chart()
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked).Select
     ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet2!$A$1:$P$4")
     ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns
     ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
     ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1000
     ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 250

     ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
     ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select

     ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
     ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
     Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
     ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
     Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Select
     Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(12).Select
     Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(15).Select
     Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

     ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
     ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
     ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart "
     Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Chart "
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your desired final chart with the code supplied, since I didn't use some of your code lines.

There is another option, a "cleaner" and more efficient way to handle charts (there is no need to select them all time, I think you did it with the MACRO recorder).

Anyway, see my code below, it gave me the exact result like with the manual step (just like in your attached images).

```
Option Explicit

Sub to_draw_chart()

Dim Sht1                   As Worksheet

' modify to your sheet name
Set Sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' change Left, Top, Width , Height according to your needs
Sht1.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnStacked, 200, 200, 500, 500).Select

With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet2!$A$1:$P$4")
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1000
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 250

    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Chart "
    .ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Chart "

    .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
    .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlAutomatic

' not sure what is the purpose with the lines below ?      
'         Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
'         ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
'         ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
'         Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
'         ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Select
'         Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
'         ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(12).Select
'         Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
'         ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(15).Select
'         Selection.Format.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
End With   

End Sub
```